# How to keep the resource locked if the jenkins job failed - lockable resource

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

This is for the test purpose. I have a testbed which have several physical DUTs deployed in this environment, and every time a developer triggers a PR, it will automatically triggers jenkins to build a firmware and deploy onto a random DUT in our test environment and perform tests.

What we want to do is to preserve the DUT if the test failed, and we can avoid the test being executed on that DUT by keep the resource locked. Is there any way to achieve that by lockable-resource?

And this is my test script.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'one_slave'
    }
    options {
        lock(resource: "DUT_1", variable: 'LOCKED_RESOURCE', quantity: 1)
    }
    stages{
        stage("test"){
            steps {
                error("Build failed because of this and that..")
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure{
            script {
                // To keep the failed DUT locked.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to import the `org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager` and use the `reserve` function, but I got the error message
`Error when executing failure post condition:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.reserve() is applicable for argument types: () values: [[resources:DUT_1, userName:Lyndon]]`
```

I've also checked this article [Jenkins lockable resource - lock without unlocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552073/jenkins-lockable-resource-lock-without-unlocking) , but I don't think it's the same scenario. My scenario is to lock the resource after the build is finished.

Comment: There is a way to cheat; You can use an input() combined with a large timeout(); The job wont be finished; but the lock will still be there, This also allows you to free a lock with a single click / simple input. But it is (a bit) clunky without nice alerting/chat integration

Comment: Thank you @Sir.Chefcoq, that's a good idea. As to the alerting integration, we do integrated with slack, so maybe I can put the `input` part to the last of my post actions, then I can be notified by Slack and also have my resource locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking if there's any available function in the `LockableResourcesManager` which I can use for my situation, I found the `steal` can do that for me.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin/blob/3a5c1a140712e4b310e60e9880bcf195fbee674e/src/main/java/org/jenkins/plugins/lockableresources/LockableResourcesManager.java#L801

So here's my solution:

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager as LRM
import java.time.LocalDateTime

pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        lock(label: "DUT_1", variable: 'LOCKED_RESOURCE', quantity: 1)
    }
    stages{
        stage("test"){
            steps {
                error("Build failed because of this and that..")
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure{
            script {
                LRM lrm = LRM.get()
                resources = lrm.getResources()
                target_resources = resources.findAll {  // since the resource name is unique, this will get the only one resource
                    resource -> resource.getName() == env.LOCKED_RESOURCE
                }
                lrm.steal(target_resources, "${currentBuild.projectName}${currentBuild.displayName}")
                Date date = new Date();
                target_resources[0].setReservedTimestamp(date)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So after the build is finished, the resource will be stolen by the `steal` step and the status will remain `reserved` status, then I can manually unreserved it.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just missed a parameter type - the resource you are trying to reserve should be wrapped into a List. See Javadocs [here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/lockable-resources/org/jenkins/plugins/lockableresources/LockableResourcesManager.html#reserve(java.util.List,java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thank you Iterokun, but after rethinking, I don't think that the `reserve` function would help since I cannot reserve a resource which is currently used by the current build. And as to the error message, I've referenced this article -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641395/create-persistent-lock-dynamically-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline to resolve that. And I thought that maybe the `setEphemeral` function would help, but it doesn't.

Comment: You could add a `post` action, that would be outside of your `lock` step and the resource should be unlocked by then.

Comment: Hi @Iterokun, could you elaborate a bit more with your suggestion? Since I couldn't tell the difference between yours and what I've done. I did add a post action within the failure condition to see if I can preserve the status of the locked resource which I specified in the `option` section to be still locked. I'm not sure if you're suggesting me to `lock` the resource in the post action again, but I've tried that and it's not working since the Lockable resource would say the resource has been reserved so it will wait for it to be released, which it could not be since the build is not done.

Comment: Right, that's the piece I missed - you lock in `options`. There is also a `lock` step you can use just like any other step with a body. That one works until you return from the closure, then the resource gets unlocked and you can reserve it again. Now that I typed this, I can see that in a highly contested environment someone else might grab that lock before your script has a chance to `reserve`. It looks like you will have to write your own `lock` implementation with conditional releasing of the resource.